# Ionic 2 iOS cors

Tags: ios, ionic2, cors

I'm running into an issue with CORS in ionic 2. When I hit my login endpoint I get the following CORS error from the `iOS build on a phone`

`[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I'm not seeing this issue from the Android version of the application. Is there a setting or something that can be enabled within the Ionic app to fix the CORS issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to set proxies in ionic.config.js like this :

```
{
  "name": "*******",
  "app_id": "******",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true,
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:8080"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is a sample project provided by Ionic with proxy setup and small server returning static data.
https://github.com/mhartington/V2Proxy

Answer (score 1):

> Workaround only - Not a perfect solution

---

I was running with the same problem, My ionic 3 app with ASP.net backend was working just fine, it was not working with IOS ( Iphone x - IoS 11 simulator ).

Finally i got a solution

### Solution

I changed the `web view` option of my ionic app.

First, open config.xml and add the following properties

`<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />`

Then remove all plugins and platforms then run or build your app

That's it

**Detailed steps given in [this url](http://uncaughterror.com/programming/ionic3/preflight-response-issue-with-ionic3-app-on-ios-build-only-resolved/)**

Answer (score 0):

At work we had this same error, only occurred in the iPhone, and after much research we discovered that this problem is referring to the server (API), not to the mobile application.

Our API is an ASP.NET application and is exposed through IIS.
I do not know if your environment is the same, but basically what solved our problem was:

On the server, in `IIS`, in the application pool of our application we changed the `Managed Pipeline Version` property from `Classic` to `Integrated`, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

I'm hitting this issue as well. The servers are NOT locally hosted, but they are not CORS enabled either. The issue is that the HTTP requests are setting the origin to `localhost`, when it should be `file://`.

Anyone know how to avoid this?

Comment: Please add additional info as a comment or in a new question